# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException When File.transferTo() is called

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've recently inherited a Java API and am having trouble with file uploads. Unfortunately, Java isn't a language I have much experience in so I'm a bit stumped by this.

The `MultiPartFile` is being received ok, and I can find the file in the temp directory, but when I try to use File.transferTo() to create the final file I just get the below error;

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\undertow3706399294849267898upload -> S:\Dev\PolicyData\Temp.xlsx

As I mentioned the temp undertow file exists, and the directory on the S drive also exist, (but there's no Temp.xlsx as my understanding is this should be created by `transferTo()`). Any solutions I've found to this problem so far are resolved using absolute file paths.

This is a simplified version of the code but the error remains the same.

SpringBoot framework is "1.5.3.RELEASE", running Java 1.8.0_131

```
    ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable Long stageFileTypeId) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            String filePath = "S:\\Dev\\PolicyData\\Temp.xlsx";
            log.info("Upload Path = {}", filePath);

            File dest = new File(filePath);
            file.transferTo(dest);

            return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(filePath));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("An error has occurred uploading the file", ex);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
    else {
        log.error("An error has occurred, no file was received");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: is it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187261/multipart-transferto-looks-for-a-wrong-file-address-when-using-createtempfile

Comment: looks similar but I'm not converting the file in another component, which was the solution to the other issue. I'm going to go through the post and try the other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API for MultipartFile is a bit tricky. The transferTo(File) method javadoc states that (bold are mine):

> This may either move the file in the filesystem, copy the file in the
>   filesystem, or save memory-held contents to the destination file. If
>   the destination file already exists, it will be deleted first.
>
> **If the target file has been moved in the filesystem, this operation
>   cannot be invoked again afterwards**. Therefore, call this method just
>   once in order to work with any storage mechanism.

It seems that the Undertow implementantion already called it to move the in-memory uploaded file to "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Loca\Temp\undertow3706399294849267898upload" so another transferTo is failing.

I came across the same problem using javax.servlet.http.Part in a Wildfly containter with Undertow.

If you are using Spring framework >= 5.1, you could try the Multipart.transferTo(Path) method, using `dest.toPath()`

Or you can copy from the inputStream, with something like this:

```
try (InputStream is = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(is, dest.toPath());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Areus, that cleared the main error. It's worth mentioning that this has also highlighted a permissions error that I was getting from trying to save to the S drive but the error was being reported as File Not Found, instead of a permissions issue. I'm adding this as a comment in case someone else runs into the same problem.