# Converting MultipartFile to File

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to convert a MultipartFile to File but  **multipartFile.transferTo(uploadedFile);** is throwing an IOException.

To me it looks like the application is looking for the uploadedFile at `'/tmp/tomcat.8080.434182389216770471/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_43f33560_23be_4189_843c_d9062cb44ec2_00000000.tmp'` instead of `src/main/resources/targetFile.tmp`

```
        @GetMapping("/reportError")
        public String error(Model model) throws MessagingException, IOException {

            EmailService emailService = new EmailService();

            File uploadedFile = new File("src/main/resources/targetFile.tmp");

            multipartFile.transferTo(uploadedFile);

            emailService.sendmail(Arrays.asList(uploadedFile, dailyReportFile, shiftReportFile));

            model.addAttribute("msg", "Thanks for reporting.\nIt helps us improve the app.");
            return "messageView";
        }
```

> java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /tmp/tomcat.8080.434182389216770471/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_43f33560_23be_4189_843c_d9062cb44ec2_00000000.tmp
> (No such file or directory)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:122)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.transferTo(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:256)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> gmailgdogra.controller.AppController.error(AppController.java:202)
> ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]   at

> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292] Caused by:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /tmp/tomcat.8080.434182389216770471/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_43f33560_23be_4189_843c_d9062cb44ec2_00000000.tmp
> (No such file or directory)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]   at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:404)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:120)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    ... 52 common frames omitted

***And my Test pass with similar code***

```
@Test
void convert() throws IOException {
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("sourceFile.tmp", "Hello World".getBytes());
File file = new File("src/main/resources/targetFile.tmp");

multipartFile.transferTo(file);
assertThat(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/targetFile.tmp"), "UTF-8"))
        .isEqualTo("Hello World");
}
```

***Below code works well if I don't send the converted Multipart file.***

```
@GetMapping("/reportError")
public String error(Model model) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    EmailService emailService = new EmailService();

    emailService.sendmail(Arrays.asList(dailyReportFile, shiftReportFile));

    model.addAttribute("msg", "Thanks for reporting.\nIt helps us improve the app.");
 
   return "messageView";
}
```

---

```
@GetMapping("/reportError")
public String error(Model model) throws MessagingException, IOException {
InputStream initialStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()];
initialStream.read(buffer);

File targetFile = new File("src/main/resources/targetFile.tmp");

try (OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)) {
    outStream.write(buffer);
}

EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
emailService.sendmail(Arrays.asList(targetFile, dailyReportFile, shiftReportFile));
model.addAttribute("msg", "Thanks for reporting.\nIt helps us improve the app.");
return "messageView";
}
```

I have tried above but it fails with message

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /tmp/tomcat.8080.486619881437185002/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_43ba6a8d_27c9_49de_a73e_4f9026fc852e_00000000.tmp
> (No such file or directory)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]   at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:194)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at

***Edit***
Similar problem [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50187261/6821605). But none of the provided solution has worked for me.

***Tried below code but it also failed***

```
 @GetMapping("/reportError")
    public String error(Model model) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
        File uploadedFile = convert(multipartFile);
        System.out.println("transferTo completed");

        emailService.sendmail(Arrays.asList(uploadedFile, dailyReportFile, shiftReportFile));

        model.addAttribute("msg", "Thanks for reporting.\nIt helps us improve the app.");
        return "messageView";
    }

    public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Turned out that I had already consumed MultipartFile in another controller method therefore it was no longer valid. Now resolved.